# One project on Windows and Android - Python

Tags: python

Is there any application(s) or possibilities that could let me work on one Python file on my PC and phone? I mean situation when I'm doing something on PC, save it, close PC, but in a middle of night I have some thought, so I don't have to open PC, but just try it on phone instead.

I guess there's a possibility with uploading it to some server after each usage, but doing it sometimes even few times per day would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Git account (Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc). Push your code there. Pull it to many devices where you can edit and re-push back.

This is not specific to Python.

If you want to **deploy** the Python code to always run the latest changes you've made, then you can setup CI/CD actions from those sites.

Comment: Thanks :) heard of GitHub, but didn't know it has so big power.

Comment: You can also run your own Git server, if you wanted